# MetPy ageostrophic wind script

Tags: python, metpy

https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/Ageostrophic_Wind_Example.html

The above script is throwing up an error. Kindly help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/rajkumar/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_14745/1049689062.py", line 5, in <module>
    '{dt:%H}00_003.grb2'.format(base_url, dt=dt))

  File "/home/rajkumar/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/siphon/http_util.py", line 387, in __init__
    self._get_metadata()

  File "/home/rajkumar/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/siphon/ncss.py", line 58, in _get_metadata
    root = ET.fromstring(meta_xml)

  File "/home/rajkumar/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1316, in XML
    return parser.close()

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the web-rendered notebooks are woefully out of date (due to problems with the backend infrastructure). Can you try using the updated notebook directly from: https://github.com/Unidata/python-training/blob/master/pages/gallery/Ageostrophic_Wind_Example.ipynb ?

Comment: Many thanks. It works, will follow this here on.